# Python Selenium - Select list item from unordered list

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Website: [https://vahan.parivahan.gov.in/vahan4dashboard/vahan/view/reportview.xhtml'](https://vahan.parivahan.gov.in/vahan4dashboard/vahan/view/reportview.xhtml%27)

I'm trying to use selenium to download data from this website but it's setup in a confusing way. I need to figure out how to use the dropdown in the list called 'Y-Axis' and select 'Maker' from that list. Then I need to hit the 'refresh' button and the 'download excel' button. This is the html of the dropdown menu:

```
<select id="yaxisVar_input" name="yaxisVar_input" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" onchange="PrimeFaces.ab({s:&quot;yaxisVar&quot;,e:&quot;change&quot;,f:&quot;masterLayout_formlogin&quot;,p:&quot;yaxisVar&quot;,u:&quot;xaxisVar&quot;});"><option value="Vehicle Category" data-escape="true">Vehicle Category</option><option value="Vehicle Class" selected="selected" data-escape="true">Vehicle Class</option><option value="Norms" data-escape="true">Norms</option><option value="Fuel" data-escape="true">Fuel</option><option value="Maker" data-escape="true">Maker</option></select>
```

This is the code I'm playing around with:

from selenium import webdriver

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/abhay.singh/chromedriver')
driver.get('https://vahan.parivahan.gov.in/vahan4dashboard/vahan/view/reportview.xhtml')

# Get the y-axis selector
# select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('yaxisVar_input'))
# select.select_by_visible_text('Maker').click()
# print(select.options)
# print([o.text for o in select.options])

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='yaxisVar_input']/option[text()='Maker']").click()
```

I'd appreciate your help in figuring this out!

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I could do. One thing to note is that selenium is not really meant for downloading, so I added a sleep at the end to ensure the download completes. It can also be done with scripts to monitor the download status, but I don't really know how to do it. I also had to add a sleep in the middle to make sure the "Maker" click was being captured correctly. I'm sure there is a better way to do that as well.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
with webdriver.Chrome() as driver:
    driver.get("https://vahan.parivahan.gov.in/vahan4dashboard/vahan/view/reportview.xhtml")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "label[id='yaxisVar_label']"))).click()
    time.sleep(2)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li[data-label='Maker']"))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "j_idt61"))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "vchgroupTable:xls"))).click()
    time.sleep(10)
```

You might be able to do this with a `requests.post()`. I didn't look into the headers or form data, but it is there.

Comment: Thank you for this, its very helpful! Do you know if there is another way to get the table data with these filters? Essentially, I need to get a few different cuts of this data based on the States & RTO filters and then clean them up with pandas

Comment: I unfortunately do not. You could look into making post requests, or using a different kind of requests library that can parse js, like requests-html.

Comment: Instead of putting `WebDriverWait(driver, 10)` on each line, declare a variable, `wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)` and then use `wait.until(...)` to clean up the code. Your first locator is just an ID that you've put inside a CSS selector. Instead just use `(By.ID, 'yaxisVar_label')`. `time.sleep()` is a very bad practice and should be removed. They aren't needed with the `WebDriverWait`s you've included anyway.